# Is it possible to alert all key value pairs at once

Tags: jquery

I want to show all key value pairs at once in a table format in two differant rows.

```
<script>     
    $(document).ready(function() {         
        var data = {  [ { "name":"zonealarm", "price":"500" , "quantity":"23" }, { "name":"kaspersky", "price":"200" , "quantity":"32" } ] };         
        $.each(data.programs, function(key,val) {             
            alert(key+val);         
        });     
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Okay. Which bit are you stuck on? Have you looked into *anything*? You say "table format with two rows" -- do you mean keys across the top, values underneath? Really in an `alert`? (You can't style alerts, it's going to be ugly.)

Comment: the question was not clear.

Comment: First of all the code snippet you gave does not work because there is no programs object in your data object. And what you want to do is not clear. What information you want to alert? Just their names? Everything? And you shouldn't use alert for such a thing anyways.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Using alert I am just checking the key value pairs. But I want to show both item details(name,price,quantity) in two different rows. Please guid me I am a fresher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just build up a string and then alert it after the `$.each` loop. You can use `\t` for a tab and `\n` for a line break.

Comment: I didn't (and it looks like whoever did undid it), but this is hardly a useful answer. (It's also a rubbish question.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, I slightly stimied the usefulness but when the question has obviously received such little effort, I'd rather give a direction than writing the code for the OP

Comment: Oh, absolutely. I wouldn't code for this question either, I just wouldn't answer at all. :-)

Comment: @AdamHopkinson : Actually I want to **show in table format. i.e. in first row name price quantity. In 2nd row  zonealarm 500 23. In 3rd row kaspersky 200 32**